# Compositing heat distortion not rendering

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to create a heat distortion effect by combining a particle layer over a background image. I can see the effect inside the compositor but when I render it only renders the particle layer. (seen bottom right) I check the Compositor option in "Post Processing" any help?

[image]

Comment: Your displace node is connected to the Viewer only.  Connect it to the Composite Node.

Answer (score 5):

Whatever is connected to the **composite** node is your final render, the **Viewer** does not get saved using the output settings.

In your current setup you are feeding just one layer directly into the Composite (output) Node, bypassing any displacement.

Connect the output of the displacement to the composite node and be happy ever after.

[image]